# AJAX method to verify username availability is not working - ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: jquery, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm making a user registration form on my website, and I have the text input for the username, and below it a span on which I want to display a message to let the user know if that username is available or not.

Here's how the html code looks for that specific field, and the span is where I want the message to appear.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Nombre de usuario">
<span id="availabilityMessage"></span>
```

To do this, I am trying to use the following jQuery method, which on the URL I refer to the action result on my controller.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#username').on('input', function () {
        var username = $(this).val();
        var availabilityMessage = $('#availabilityMessage');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Login/CheckUsernameAvailability',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { username: username },
            success: function (result) {
                availabilityMessage.removeClass('red-text green-text');

                if (result.isAvailable) {
                    availabilityMessage.addClass('green-text');
                    availabilityMessage.text('Username Available');
                } else {
                    availabilityMessage.addClass('red-text');
                    availabilityMessage.text('Username Not Available');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Action Result on LoginController:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult CheckUsernameAvailability(string username)
{
   // Query to check if the username that is being input already exists
   bool isUsernameAvailable = (from u in dbContext.Usuarios
                               where u.Username == username
                               select u).Any();

   return Json(new { isAvailable = isUsernameAvailable });
}
```

When I load the page and try writing on the Username field, no message appears, and it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I'm referencing correctly to the .js file with the jQuery code, so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Is there any other way to approach this or am I simply doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you tried debugging the c# code to see what username is being checked and what the database is returning?

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.9 or later you'd probably want to use `method` instead of `type`, but either way they default to `GET` so can probably be omitted. Have you tried including the `cache: false` option in case the browser is "helping" by not submitting what it thinks are duplicate requests?